# Restriction of Hecke Characters

Tags: number-theory, hecke-characters

Let $L$ be a number field and let $\Psi$ be a finite order Hecke character on $L$ with (finite part) of conductor as $\mathfrak{f}$. Suppose we define $$\psi(m) :=\Psi(m\mathcal{O}_L)$$ for all integers $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Does $\psi$ define a Dirichlet character? If so what is the modulus?

I kind of feel that this should be true and the modulus should be $\mathfrak{f}\cap\mathbb{Z}$ but I don't know how to go about it.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It might be simpler to think about idele-class-group characters restricted to a diagonally imbedded idele-class-group of subfield.

Comment: Is this the embedding you are talking about? $\mathbb{Q}^\times\hookrightarrow L^\times \hookrightarrow \mathbb{A}_L^\times$ ?

Comment: Yes. To my taste, it gives a cleaner picture of the local info.

Comment: I shall try to write down the details, thank you for the suggestion... :)